# Identifying Subject-Verb Pair In a long sentence

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Lately I have been having some trouble trying to find the subject-verb pair in long sentences.

For Example :

> I have a dream that my four little children will one day live in a nation where they will not be judged by the color of their skin but by the content of their character. - MLK, Jr.

Breaking this sentence down, I can identify three parts:

> I have a dream...
>
> ...*that* my four little children will one day live in a nation...
>
> ...*where* they will not be judged by the color of their skin but by the content of their character.

I have been able to identify that the 2nd and 3rd are dependent/subordinate clauses. Now identifying the subject-verb pairs :

> **I** **have** a dream...

Subject : *I*

Verb : *Have*

> ...that **my** four little **children** **will** one day **live** in a nation...

Subject : *My children*

Verb : *Will live* or Just *will* ? or just *live* ?(Will is the helping verb ?).

Both *One day* and *in an nation* are describing the verb **live** ?

> ...where **they** **will not be judged** by the color of their skin but by the content of their character.

Subject : *they*

Verb : *will not be judged*, just *will*, *not be judged* or *judged* ?

How can i identify verb in such situations ?

Also, what function is *but*  playing here ? Ensuring parallelism in the last part of the phrase ?

Thanks.

Comment: You've raised a lot of issues about parsing clauses, including the complex matter of catenative constructions. I'd draw you a syntax tree, but there wouldn't be enough room for it! Suffice to say that "[they will [not be judged]]", for example, is not a single clause but two, as shown.

Answer (score 0):

Future tense  in English is rather contrived with the help of the  modals, SHALL and WILL without which the events cannot be distanced in future.  The verbs after SHALL/WILL are infinitives without  TO, a common occurrence after most of the modals. Better view the verb as Verb phrase in future tense.

- Verb : Will live
- Verb : will be judged ( "NOT"an adverb)("be" is intrigal to verb phrase in passive construction)

In other analysis , you are absolutely right.

BUT has nothing to do with parallelism in grammar. It is an adversative conjunction used to express contrast between the two statements. Of course, there is fine parallelism at the end and BUT as a conjunction plays its  limited role.